# What is the most secure solution to send ajax request and prevent data manipulation?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Consider i implemented a HTML5 game with JS, and i intended to save the records into the database, and all js files are minified and obfuscated already. But the result of client score is saved into a variable and we just want to save that score somehow in server-side (php).

What is the best possible solution to prevent users from cheating and updating their scores using FireBug, or similar client side developer tools? I know it may be not possible protecting it 100% but i want to do it as best as possible.

By the way as HTML5 applications are extending rapidly there should be solution to secure health of data transmission some how.

Thanks

Comment: ajax is from client. client can never be trusted. however if you want to verify that the data sent from server at first place wasnt altered  - you can send a hash to the client. and when the ajax is called - send also the hash value. then in server you can digest again and check.

Comment: _“I know it may be not possible protecting it 100% but i want to do it as best as possible.”_ – then just do _nothing_, because it is not possible _at all_.

Comment: @CBroe - It may not be 100% possible, There is of course value in *making it difficult*

Comment: @techfoobar: Not really – that just makes it _unfair_, because who will/can cheat will depend on the users technical skills … and that is not fair, unless it is actually a “hacking” game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it may be not possible protecting it 100% but i want to do it
>   as best as possible.

Of course it's not possible; your code runs on the client's machine, so the client has full control over it. You can't keep any secrets -- you can obfuscate to your heart's content, but at the end of the day I can still see, intercept and modify your HTTP requests on a whim.

The only way to keep control of things is to have the client report *actions* which the server validates based on its knowledge of the game state; the server then sends to the client the *results* of these actions so that a friendly client can keep its notion of game state coherent with that of the server's.

If you are not prepared to do that, simply do not bother. If you depend on clients not being hostile in even the slightest degree, *all it takes is just one person* with time to kill to troll you into oblivion.

Answer (score 2):

1) If possible, use HTTPS;

2) At server side, put a random key (that you can validate in postback) in http header;

3) At client-side, key-encrypt your score using this random key. So you will have each time a different encrypted score even if the score remains the same;

4) Put the encrypted score and your random key inside the http header;

5) Put the score not crypted in query string to cheat your users (The true encrypted score is inside your http header). Post your data;

6) At server-side, ignore the cheated score in query string and decrypt the score in http header using the key (that is also in http header). Before decrypt, don't forget to validate the key;

7) You can also verify if your encrypted score and cheated score are the same, so you can know witch users are cheating.

Comment: Thanks you just invented CSRF :D

Comment: Because noone will think to look at the HTTP headers... sigh.

Comment: You're right, Jon, we can just make the life difficult to cheaters. For example, in my sites, my random keys have a brief ttl. So the cheaters can't easily and manually create requests because when they finish it, the random key has expired.

Answer (score 1):

We just developed a browser-based game and had exactly the same problem. The most secure way would be to do the whole game-logic on the server but that might be a lot of work. What we ended up doing is hide an operation in the javascript code, and then calculated a number based on that operation, then we store the score and that number in a cookie and checked them on the server side.

Example:
the user scores 235 -> saved in a cookie

operation: 235 -> (2 + 3 + 5) * 3.19 -> store result in a cookie (3.19 is a random number we chose)

Send the score to the server

On the server get the score cookie and do the same operation, if the score and the operation are the same as those stored in the cookies, accept the score, else refuse it.
It's still not 100% secure, but we have almost 2000 scores stored and none of them seems hacked

Comment: So what do you do when you start seeing hacked scores? Start playing whack-a-mole against the internet or pull the leaderboards entirely? To me it seems illogical to spend resources on implementing a feature that can only continue to exist depending on the "generosity" of the players.

Comment: Of course you can't protect it 100%. In our case, it seemed like a good enough solution to avoid the most obvious "hacks", it was the best balance between using resources and getting protection. A prize will be given out to one of the players chosen randomly between all those who participated, so the score doesn't play any role. We just didn't want new players to be demotivated by incredibly high (and hacked) scores.